# How to extract a substring and add it to original string with sed?

Tags: sed, find-and-replace, sh

I am trying to write an sh script witch receives a string as input, extracts a particular substring and adds it after an specified expression to the input string. I tried a lot with `sed -i'N` ... but nothing works.

This is an example of input string:

```
<img src="images/Button-7.jpg" width="251" height="129" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
```

This is what I am trying to get as output:

```
<img src="images/Button-7.jpg" name="Button-7" width="251" height="129" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
```

Following works. But I have to declare every Button by hand.

```
VarA='Button-7.jpg'
VarB='Button-7.jpg" name="Button-7'

sed "s/${VarA}/${VarB}/g" index.html > temp.html
mv temp.html index.html
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me that you need to employ group capture and backreferences to get this to work well. Playing around a little with there concepts, I came up with the following that worked well for what I understand your use case to be:

```
sed 's#src="images/\(.*\).jpg"#& name="\1"#'
```

The interesting things here are:

1. Using `#` as the separator instead of the regular `/`. This makes it easier to reason about because it doesn't require escaing the forward slashes in the pattern.
2. Capturing the input within a group using the (escaped) parentheses.
3. Re-using the entire match with `&` (hat tip: G-man).
4. Back-referencing the captured group in the replacement text (`\1`).

Comment: (1) I assume that you didn't mean to change `.jpg` to `.jp`. (2) You shouldn't need to escape the quotes (i.e., `\"`). (3) You should be able to use `&` to substitute the entire _found string_; for example, `sed 's#src="images/\(.*\).jpg"#& name="\1"#'`.

Comment: Thanks, great suggestions -- I will apply those updates. That makes the whole thing a lot nicer.